# Colliding input to compression function

Tags: hash, block-cipher

So I recently started to look into cryptography and found the following question to cryptography scheme using $T = E_{S}(S \oplus M)$

It is said that this is not secure because you can have a colliding input.

I am now not sure how to find this input, that leads to the same Hash.

Would be wonderful, if someone could help me out here.

Comment: What happens if M=S for two different values of M?

Comment: And there are many pairs apart from the equality of two

Comment: @SEJPM but does my key not prevent this? I would still have T = E_S(0) or am I mistaken? Which is not the same as T = E_S~(0). This would still produce a different hash or not?  I would like to find a F(S,M) = F(S~, M~)

Comment: You are right of course, that equality isn't sufficient for collision, I didn't think this one throgh properly enough.

Comment: This still brings me no step closer to the solution though... As far as I am aware, there must be a solution for F(S,M) = F(S~, M~)

Comment: OK, new and better hint: Start with $E_S(S\oplus m)=E_{\widetilde S}(\widetilde S\oplus \widetilde T)$ and see if you can derive a value (eg for $\widetilde T$) that yields a collision.